# Issue with user-defined array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create an array using cin to define the size. While that seems to be working (based on what I currently have), none of the other stuff I want to do seems to be working.

For instance, I want to use a for loop to find the smallest int in the array since I will then need to compare it with all the other ints in the array, but no matter where I have the statement to return the smallest int, it does not do it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


  int userSize;
  cout << "Please define size of array: ";
  cin >> userSize;

  int *duckArray = new int[userSize];

  for (int i = 0; i < userSize; i++) {
    cout << "Please enter a number into the array: ";
    cin >> duckArray[i];
  }

  int smallest = duckArray[0];

  for (int i = 0; i < userSize; i++){
    if (duckArray[i] < smallest){
        smallest = duckArray[i];
        cout << smallest << endl;
    }
  }

  //cout << smallest << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Return the smallest int to where?  All you have is the `main` function.

Comment: Is it printing out the correct smallest value?  Your code looks right.

Comment: FWIW: `std::min_element` will perform the search for you.

Comment: @Buddy No. It just immediately closes. The reason why I have the commented out code is because I tried it originally like that, but the same thing happened.

Comment: you should `delete[]` your array on the end or even better to use smart pointer

Comment: It works, just don't make the smallest number the first one (or nothing will print out).... or follow @ul90's answer.  :)

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: @BobSmith: It sounds like your real problem is "it immediately closes". Are you running through Visual Studio? You need to get the console window to stay open through program termination.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working if you change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userSize; i++){
    if (duckArray[i] < smallest){
        smallest = duckArray[i];
    }
}

cout << smallest << endl;
```

This will find and print the smallest number entered.

Comment: I tried that already, but when I saw that that did not work, I commented the cout out, and put it in the for loop. Unfortunately, the results are the same for me.

Comment: i just tried it and it worked (enter 3 for array size and then then numbers 5, 3 and 1 and it will print 1)

Comment: I guess Visual Studio is just not liking me, because it immediately closes after I fill in the array.

Comment: maybe this is the problem: your IDE is hiding the result output. Just run it from console and you should see the correct result.

Comment: or just add `int x; cin >> x;` at the end of the code (just before `return 0`). This will wait for another (dummy) input.

Comment: @BobSmith. Add `system("pause");` before `return 0;`

Comment: I just realized something which made me realize that I should probably not code when I'm sick. I changed the return statement to: system("pause"); and then this worked perfectly.

Comment: @AndyG this will not work on OSX or Linux - there is no program "pause" by default

Comment: @AndyG I noticed that right before you posted that. Feeling spacey right now. Thank you though. :)

Comment: @ul90: He mentioned he was using Visual Studio as his IDE, so it was a pretty safe bet he was using Windows :-)

Answer (score -3):

Arrays in C++ must have their size declared to the compiler at runtime. Other people are going to explain how you can buffer memory to simulate a dynamically allocating arrays. You can also have your Array at a given size and as the user adds and removes, you can reject inputs over the current size.

I highly recommend you look into [Vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). Vectors are much like `ArrayLists` in Java. They are a form of higher level collections that resize themselves as you add more elements to them.

Comment: You can in fact allocate arrays: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-9a-dynamically-allocating-arrays/

Comment: As I said, you can do a workaround with pointers. See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/89634/) as well for the same question asked years ago and the  same answer as the one I provided. Using vectors here is a much better solution.

Comment: the thing with the pointers is not a "workaround", it's legal C++ code. But vectors are safer and easier to use. But in this case, this would not solve the problem.

Comment: Using a pointer to allocate memory dynamically for an array is not a workaround. In fact, that's what `vector` itself is doing under the hood.